# What does create an original Illustration

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am not sure what it means to create an original illustration can someone please help me.

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the [Help Center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about this site. The reason  your question has gotten down votes is probably because you did not give any context (it sound like you just wanted the words "original illustration" defined...) and didn't show effort (such as explaining what you thought "original illustration" means). This question actually does have a lot of nuances, so I think it's a good question. For example, is an image that I didn't create but have an exclusive license to use "original"?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that when someone asks for an original illustration they want something you made and not a rip off something that already exists.

So basically an illustration done from scratch.

Usually when people use the term "original" it is related to the fact that what you are providing is one of the kind and you are its sole author.

Comment: Well even if made form scratch it is some kind of ripoff of some concept somewhere in time ;)

Comment: Ahaha I know what you mean. You can't run away from influences. Being influenced by some kind of style of great work is acceptable but taking someone else's work as yours won't be. Keeping a good balance between influence and your own work would be ideal.